# Vectorising an equation using numpy

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, numpy, scipy

[image]

[image]

I am trying to implement the above formula as a vectorised form.
`K=3` here, `X` is `150x4` numpy array. `mu` is `3x4` numpy array. `Gamma` is a `150x3` numpy array. `Sigma` is a `kx4x4` numpy array. Therefore `Sigma[k]` is a `4x4` numpy array. `N=150`

```
N_k = np.sum(Gamma, axis=0)
for k in range(K): # Correct
         x_new = X - mu[k] #Correct
         a = np.dot(x_new.T, x_new) #Incorrect from here I feel
         for i in range(len(data)):
             sigma[k] = Gamma[i][k] * a
         sigma[k]=sigma[k]/N_k #totally incorrect
```

How to fix this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A sum of products? sounds like a job for [np.einsum](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.einsum.html):

```
import numpy as np
N = 150
K = 3
M = 4
x = np.random.random((N,M))
mu = np.random.random((K,M))
gamma = np.random.random((N,K))

xbar = x-mu[:,None,:] # shape (3, 150, 4)
sigma = np.einsum('nk,knm,kno->kmo', gamma, xbar, xbar)
sigma /= gamma.sum(axis=0)[:,None,None]
```

---

**Decoding `'nk,knm,kno->kmo'`**:

This subscript specification has three components to the left of the array (`->`) followed by one component to the right.

The three components on the left correspond with the subscripts for `gamma`, `xbar` and `xbar`, the operands being passed to `np.einsum`.

`gamma` has subscript `nk`, just as in the formula you posted.
`xbar` has shape (3, 150, 4). You can think of it as having subscript `knm`, where `k` and `n` have the same meaning as in the formula you posted, and `m` is a subscript representing the axis of length 4 which is not explicitly mentioned in your formula, but is apparently there given your description of the shape of the arrays.

Now the third subscript component is `kno`. The `o` subscript is used because the `o` plays the same role as the `m` subscript, but we *don't want summation over `m`*. In fact, we want the `m` and `o` subscripts to be iterated over independently, not in lock-step. Hence we give the third subscript different letters.

Notice that `n` appears in the subscripts on the left (`nk, knm, kno`), but does not appear on the right (in `kmo`). That tells `np.einsum` to sum over `n`.

The `k` appears in the subscripts on the left *and* on the right. This tells `np.einsum` that we wish to advance the `k` subscript in lock-step, but (since it appears on the right) we don't want to sum over `k`.

Since `kmo` appears on the right, these subscripts remain in the result. This results in `sigma` having shape `(K,M,M)` (i.e. (3,4,4)).

Comment: This is just amazing. Thank you for teaching me something new!

Answer (score 2):

Just a couple of performance pointers on top of unubtu's great answer.

`np.einsum` has trouble optimizing calls with more than two arguments. Whenever possible, it is generally faster to manually split the calculations into groups of two arguments, e.g.:

```
def unubtu():
    xbar = x-mu[:,None,:] # shape (3, 150, 4)
    sigma = np.einsum('nk,knm,kno->kmo', gamma, xbar, xbar)
    sigma /= gamma.sum(axis=0)[:,None,None]
    return sigma

def faster():
    xbar = x-mu[:,None,:] # shape (3, 150, 4)
    sigma = np.einsum('knm,kno->kmo', gamma.T[..., None] * xbar, xbar)
    sigma /= gamma.sum(axis=0)[:,None,None]
    return sigma

In [50]: %timeit unubtu()
10000 loops, best of 3: 147 µs per loop

In [51]: %timeit faster()
10000 loops, best of 3: 129 µs per loop
```

A 12% improvement isn't much, but the difference can get (much) larger with larger arrays.

Also, even though `np.einsum` is a great tool, that makes very difficult things easy, it is by no means as optimized as `np.dot` is if your numpy is built with a good linear algebra library. In your case, given that `K` is small, using `np.dot` and a Python loop is even faster:

```
def even_faster():
    sigma = np.empty((K, M, M))
    for k in xrange(K):
        x_ = x - mu[k]
        sigma[k] = np.dot((x_ * gamma[:, k, None]).T, x_)
    sigma /= gamma.sum(axis=0)[:,None,None]
    return sigma

In [52]: %timeit even_faster()
10000 loops, best of 3: 101 µs per loop
```